# How do I get the site url from a Block (within the block editor)

Tags: multisite, rest-api, block-editor, site-url

I have a block in which I'd like to display a link based on the site url. So for example, when the user enters "Futuristic", the link will display as https://my-site.com/futuristic/

I've looked at [REST API `/settings/` endpoint](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/reference/settings/), which is supposed to include a **url** field, but it doesn't (at least on the two different sites I tried). Perhaps this is because I've got WP set up as multisite. There still should be a way to access the current site's url I'm sure.

I've looked into what `wp.data.select()` can provide in the various namespaces, but I don't see anything that would include the site url.

I tried looking at output of `wp.data.select('core').getSite()` (see [Hardeep's suggestion](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/383114/2044)), but mine has no url property and looks like this:

```
{ 
  date_format: "F j, Y"
  default_category: 1
  default_comment_status: "open"
​  default_ping_status: "open"
​  default_post_format: "0"
​  description: ""
​  language: ""
​  posts_per_page: 10
​  start_of_week: 0
​  time_format: "g:i a"
​  timezone: "America/New_York"
​  title: "The Name of My Site"
​  use_smilies: true
}
```

I suspect the difference has to do with Multisite being enabled, but not sure.

Comment: There is no `getSite` selector in core `namespace`. I even tried searching Gutenberg's github.

Comment: @Lovor This is not correct. Open your block editor for a post. In your browser console type `wp.data.select('core').getSite()` and you should see the results as described above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Perhaps this is because I've got WP set up as multisite.

Yes, that's right, WordPress disables the `siteurl` (and also `admin_email`) settings on a Multisite — see [`register_initial_settings()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/register_initial_settings/) for the source.

And I don't know why they disable those (two) settings, but you can explicitly enable them like so for the `url`/`siteurl` setting, which for example, would go in the theme's `functions.php` file:

```php
// I copied this from the source..
register_setting(
    'general',
    'siteurl',
    array(
        'show_in_rest' => array(
            'name'   => 'url',
            'schema' => array(
                'format' => 'uri',
            ),
        ),
        'type'         => 'string',
        'description'  => __( 'Site URL.' ),
    )
);
```

Tried & tested working with WordPress 5.6.1 Multisite.

And also, `wp.data.select( 'core' ).getSite()` uses the Settings endpoint, so it's normal that the `url` property is missing by default on a Multisite.

Apart from that, `getSite()` caches the API results, so you'd need to *reload* the post editing screen/page in order for `getSite()` to give you the correct result, i.e. with the `url` property.

Comment: How did you find about this getSite selector? I cannot find it in documentation, nor in Gutenberg code in repository. However, it does work. Can you point to code where it is added?

Comment: @Lovor, sorry for the late reply, but it's nice to know you already [found it](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/412508/137402) 

Answer (score 0):

You can use `wp_localize_script` to pass anything you want, including site URL, to the editor as a global variable:

```
wp_localize_script(
    'script_name',
    'my_data',
    [
        'siteUrl' => get_site_url()
    ]
);
```

And then you can get it in the editor from `window.my_data.siteUrl` variable. Here `script_name` will be the script that you're enqueuing to the editor.

If you want to use the Data API, you can use `wp.data.select( 'core' ).getSite();` and once the promise has resolved, you can use the URL property.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for that. That is one way, but I thought there might be a more built-in way. By the way, it is preferred to use `wp_add_inline_script()` instead of `wp_localize_script()`

Comment: If you want to use Data API then you can use the `wp.data.select( 'core' ).getSite();`, once the promise resolves, you can use the URL property to get the website URL.

Comment: Thank you. My getSite() output is different than what you got. I added it to my question.

Comment: Unfortunately, there's no better way, at least in my knowledge, that will work. :(

Answer (score -1):

There is only this post give me the best answer and I do some research on my own.

I found a way but doesn't know it's a great method or not. But I will share it here.

```
import { useSelect } from '@wordpress/data'

const siteUrl = useSelect(select => {
    const site = select('core').getSite();
    return site && site.url;
});
```

and you can pass {siteUrl} anywhere you want to retrive the site url in edit.js.

don't know why

return site && site.url;

worked.

I ask chatgpt and it work perfectly.