# Where is getSite selector defined?

Tags: block-editor

While digging recently on how to find site url from block editor, I found [this article](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/383093/how-do-i-get-the-site-url-from-a-block-within-the-block-editor), where I found my answer, as site url is a property of object `getSite` returns.

Now, I searched through the Gutenberg code (trunk version from github) to find definition of `getSite` selector, but I was unable to find it's definition.

Can someone point me to definition of this selector in code, I want to inspect code a little better to see what paramater (if any) does it take?

P.S.
most of the selectors in 'core' store are defined in gutenberg/packages/core-data/src/selectors.ts, but this is not, yet, it is present in the store.

Answer (score 2):

I found it - it is dynamically injected as entity in gutenberg/packages/core-data/src/index.js, on line 22

```
const entitySelectors = rootEntitiesConfig.reduce( ( result, entity ) => {
    const { kind, name } = entity;
    result[ getMethodName( kind, name ) ] = ( state, key, query ) =>
        selectors.getEntityRecord( state, kind, name, key, query );
    result[ getMethodName( kind, name, 'get', true ) ] = ( state, query ) =>
        selectors.getEntityRecords( state, kind, name, query );
    return result;
}, {} );
```

While entities are defined in gutenberg/packages/core-data/src/entities.js,
it is this entity:

```
    {
        label: __( 'Site' ),
        name: 'site',
        kind: 'root',
        baseURL: '/wp/v2/settings',
        getTitle: ( record ) => {
            return get( record, [ 'title' ], __( 'Site Title' ) );
        },
    },
```

EDIT:
getSite does not take any parameters and it returns object with following properties:

```
0: "title"​
1: "description"​
2: "url"​
3: "email"​
4: "timezone"​
5: "date_format"​
6: "time_format"​
7: "start_of_week"​
8: "language"​
9: "use_smilies"
10: "default_category"​
11: "default_post_format"​
12: "posts_per_page"​
13: "show_on_front"​
14: "page_on_front"​
15: "page_for_posts"​
16: "default_ping_status"​
17: "default_comment_status"​
18: "site_logo"​
19: "site_icon"
```